# Multi-tenant access to a Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

I want to share a Postgres database with multiple tenants. Is there a way I can provide each tenant a user such that their queries are "re-written" with filters? For example, if user 'bob' of tenant 'bobsbatteries' connects to the database and does a select on 'item', its rewritten to filter out anything not related to 'bobsbatteries':

```
select * from items
```

becomes

```
select * from items where tenant='bobsbatteries'
```

It should work with select, updates and deletes with joins, subqueries etc.

Comment: Check [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html)